# Show only json calls in network tab

Tags: json, debugging, google-chrome

I want **only the json calls to be visible** in the network panel.

Since a number of image and text calls are recorded, its hard to locate the ajax json response
during debugging.

Is there a filter which can display all json request/response in the network tab **only**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click on XHR to show your ajax calls, is that what you are looking for?
Go to the Network tab in the developer console, and then click XHR at the bottom to filter by this.

Comment: This will also display HTML responses, which is not what was asked for.

Answer (score 14):

You may also filter by Content-Type/mime-type: `mime-type:application/json`
[image: Filter by Content-Type/mime-type]

See [Sorting and filtering](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#sorting-and-filtering) and [Network Filters](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/dfda76bdef18d85914a625544e4b736d86947c6d/LayoutTests/inspector/network/network-filter-parser-expected.txt)

Comment: should be:  `mime-type:text/javascript`.  This works for me.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637278/is-there-a-way-to-filter-network-requests-using-google-chrome-developer-tools/27770139#27770139

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use this highlighted option to view only `XHR` requests.

[image]