# Regex expression to only exclude urls with .css or .png file extension but allow all other urls

Tags: regex, google-chrome

I am using chrome regex filter, to filter out the url list.

I am using the following regex:

```
^.*\.(?!css$|png|js|gif$)[^.]+$
```

Although is does also excludes urls that end with `?=`

The urls that i could like to exclude are:

```
http://something.com/something.png
https://something.com/something.something.png
```

The urls that i would like to include are:

```
http://something.com/something
https://something.com/something/
http://something.com/something?=something
https://something.com/something?_=something
http://something.com/something.php
```

Comment: Why should you care if it's at the end or anywhere else.  Why not just match all strings that don't have (.css|.png|.js|.gif)?

Comment: ^((?!(\.js|\.css|\.gif|\.png)).)*$

Comment: the regex above does not filter out anything. but your right i would like to filter out those 4 file extensions while keeping everything else. screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/wyp65u74n/

Comment: Well my friend Chrome Regex in the developer tools section is weird.  That's all I can say.  I'm not 100% clear on it -- but it's definitely filtering more than just the name.  It seems to filter the content as well.  Also it doesn't seem to be true regex -- it's like some hack job of regex.  I tried a bunch of things and couldn't get any of them to work right.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637278/is-there-a-way-to-filter-network-requests-using-google-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I found something that I think works for what you're wanting.  It's not regex...but it is chrome developer tools filtering:

```
-mime-type:image/jpeg -mime-type:application/javascript -mime-type:text/css -mime-type:image/png -mime-type:image/gif
```

Make sure you uncheck the regex box.  Then you should be good to go.

The `-` means "not include"

Full credit to: [Is there a way to filter network requests using Google Chrome developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637278/is-there-a-way-to-filter-network-requests-using-google-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: -mime-type:image/jpeg -mime-type:application/x-javascript -mime-type:text/css -mime-type:image/png -mime-type:image/gif

your solution worked, just had to add "x-" in front of javascript