# Chrome dev tools: any way to exclude requests whose URL matches a regex?

Tags: regex, google-chrome, networking, google-chrome-devtools

Unfortunately in the last versions of Chrome the negative network filter doesn't work anymore. I used this filter in order to exclude each http call containing a particular string. I asked a solution in Chrome dev tool forum but at the moment nobody answered.

So I would like to know if there is a way to resolve this problem (and exclude for example each call containing the string 'loadMess') with regex syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to filter network requests using Google Chrome developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637278/is-there-a-way-to-filter-network-requests-using-google-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 149):

**Update (2018):**

This is an update to my old answer to clarify that **both bugs have been fixed for some time now**.

1. Negate or exclude filtering is working as expected now. That means you can filter request paths with `my.com/path` (show requests matching this), or `-my.com/path` (show requests not matching this).
2. The regex solution also works after my PR fix made it in production. That means you can also filter with `/my.com.path/` and `/^((?!my.com/path).)*$/`, which will achieve the same result.

I have left the old answer here for reference, and it also explains the negative lookup solution.

---

The pre-defined negative filters do work, but it doesn't currently allow you to do `NOT` filters on the names in Chrome stable, only `CONTAINS`. This is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611428) that has been fixed in Chrome Canary.

Once the change has been pushed to Chrome stable, you should be able to do `loadMess` to filter only for that name, and `-loadMess` to filter out that name and leave the rest, as it was previously.

[image: Negative Filter]

### Workaround: Regex for matching a string not containing a string

```
^((?!YOUR_STRING).)*$
```

#### Example:

```
^((?!loadMess).)*$
```

#### Explanation:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?!loadMess)` - Negative lookahead (at this cursor, do not match the next bit, without capturing)
- `.` - Match any character (except line breaks)
- `()*` - 0 or more of the preceeding group
- `$` - End of string

### Update (2016):

I discovered that there is actually a bug with how DevTools deals with Regex in the Network panel. This means the workaround above doesn't work, despite it being valid.

The Network panel filters on Name and Path (as discovered from the source code), but it does two tests that are OR'ed. In the case above, if you have `loadMess` in the Name, but not in the Path (e.g. not the domain or directory), it's going to match on either. To clarify, `true || false === true`, which means it will only filter out `loadMess` if it's found in both the Name and Path.

I have created an issue in Chromium and have subsequently pushed a [fix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=630852) to be reviewed. This has subsequently been [merged](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/c002b266f83798e8c652a641f74b381f7fb82171).

Comment: really complete explanation but it does not work... An example here: https://s31.postimg.org/53odofq23/Schermata_del_2016_07_22_15_17_59.png. I have Chrome version 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit)

Comment: @suikoy I've spent the last hour trying everything and can't see why it is failing. I tested in JavaScript and it works fine for me. There could be something dodgy with the Regex parser used in DevTools. I'm going to keep looking into this. In the meantime, I guess just use Chrome Canary.

Comment: in fact before writing here I did some test with regex but chrome behaviour is very strange and I surrendered.. Thanks anyway for support ;)

Comment: @suikoy I found the issue in the source code! I'm going to look into fixing it. It will be super cool if I manage to set things up and make a pull request. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: great! Find a solution without using Canary or Chrome beta would be perfect

Comment: @Gideon awesome work. Where can I find the fixed version after your push gets merged?

Comment: @HussienK It was fixed in [54.0.2832.2](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/54.0.2832.2/?s=c002b266f83798e8c652a641f74b381f7fb82171).

Comment: edit: the negative lookahead is not working, `-stringToAvoid` seems to work and I will be using that

Comment: Negative lookahead does not work. 
But "-my_regex" does work. Like this: -/(Violation|HMR)/

Comment: Works! Any way to save this so as to not have to retype it every time?

Comment: Not work for  `-chrome-extension://`. Any way to exclude chrome-extension requests?

Answer (score 51):

This is answered here - for latest Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27770139/4772631

E.g.: If I want to exclude all gifs then just type `-gif`
[image: Here is a short example]

Comment: As of July 2019, this works well for me for simple strings

Comment: I was attempting to specifically exclude certain domain requests that are frequently generated, such as socket.io requests. It's a simple solution and it works effectively.

Answer (score 29):

Negative lookahead is recommended everywhere, but it does not work.

Instead, "-myregex" does work for me. Like this: `-/(Violation|HMR)/`.

Comment: This may be the only correct answer at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

**Filtering multiple different urls**

You can negate symbol for filtering the network call.
Eg: `-lab.com` would filter lab.com urls.

But for filtering multiple urls you can use the | symbol in the regex
Eg: `-/lab.com|mini.com/` This will filter lab.com and mini.com as well you can use it to filter many different websites or urls.

Answer (score 3):

`Chrome broswer dev tools` support regrex filter not very well.
When I want to hide some requests, it does not work as showed above. But you can use `-hide1` `-hide2` to hide the request you want.
Just leave a space between the conditions, and this does not match the regrex, I guess it may use string match other than regrex in principle

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Invert" option to exclude the APIs matching a string in the Filter text box.

Answer (score 1):

On latest chrome version (62) you have to use :

```
-mime-type:image/gif
```