# Query Chrome inspector network tab logs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working in an app that makes many Ajax calls and results in a huge Network log in the Chrome inspector. I know that there are ways to query by things like [mime-type](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference), but I'm looking for a more fully-featured query capability.

For example, I'd like to be able to only see the pub/sub polling calls with a query like:

```
request_url:match(/pubnub.com/)
```

Or just see the GETs with:

```
request_method:GET
```

Is there a tool that makes queries like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a several options available. There are various pre-defined filter modes, as mentioned in the [Network Analysis Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filter) (as you referenced in your question).

You can use the `method` filter with `method:GET` or `method:POST` in the input to only show requests of a particular method type. If you place a `-` beforehand, the filter will negate, e.g. `-method:GET`, will show all requests other than ones that are GETs.

There's also a filter type called `domain`, which is useful for only showing requests that match a particular domain. The options are limited though:

- `domain:stackoverflow.com` would show all requests for the StackOverflow domain.
- `domain:*.google.co.uk` would show all requests that are sub-domains
  of Google UK.

**Filtering request path (Method 1)**

There's a better approach to filtering particular request paths. You can simply put `pubnub.com` in the filter input and it will match exactly what you put. You can also negate it with `-` beforehand, so entering `-pubnub.com` will show all requests that don't contain that in the path.

**Filtering request path (Method 2)**

You can also use Regex in the filter input, but not for the special filter modes (e.g. `method`, `domain`, etc.). So, in your case you could also use `/pubnub.com/` as you filter. You can do more complex regular expressions, for instance, using `/^((?!pubnub.com).)*$/` would do the equivalent of `-pubnub.com` via negative lookahead.

The reason I highlight **Method 2** is because I fixed the feature a while ago in DevTools, as a result of another similar question that ended up being a bug in **Method 1**. Both bugs are completely fixed now though. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524801/chrome-dev-tool-any-way-to-exclude-each-call-containing-a-string-with-regex/38525421#38525421) for history of the problem if you're interested.