# how not to display requests to devtools by domain

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

How not to display requests to devtools by domain?

For example, I don’t want to display requests by domain mc.yandex.ru in chrome.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome DevTools can't filter **except** rules
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#filter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to filter network requests using Google Chrome developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637278/is-there-a-way-to-filter-network-requests-using-google-chrome-developer-tools)